# Can I use the Olympic logo in a card within my board game?

Tags: trademark, fair-use

I'm publishing a board game and one of my cards is called "The Olympics" and has the logo in pixel art (Photo link: https://ibb.co/f5yocQ). I know that the logo and the words "The Olympics" have had many issues with fair use over time. I'm selling the game, but I'm not advertising the game in any way using The Olympics or the Olympic logo. It is simply a card that triggers an event (The Olympics) in-game. Is it legal for me to do this?

Comment: The US Olympics Committee has even asked people not to mention the Olympic mountain range (In WA state) in the form of "The Olympics", where it might suggest some sort of sponsorship or affiliation with the Committee or international sports competition.

Answer (score 1):

### Not at all

You are violating both the copyright and trademark of the IOC and the IOC is very vigorous in defending its IP.

Comment: Any sources for this?

Comment: Since the Olympic flag was adopted and published in 1914, it's in the public domain in most (all?) the world, and there is no copyright violation. Anyway, trademark issues are independent of copyright.